# What's best solution to use facebook SDK NOW in Xamarin.forms - PCL project?

Tags: facebook, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm making app with using Xamarin.forms. (PCL project)

I want to use facebook SDK to use
- get my profile. (name, e-mail)
- get my friends list. (their account id)
- posting on my wall.

I searched it and there are many options for that.
And Some solution seems like out of date. (not updated)

1. using Xamarin.Auth. (Component)
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cyq_ho4QflQ

   - looks like it's not using facebook app to log in that user installed on their phone.
2. The Outercurve Foundation's Facebook SDK (Component) https://components.xamarin.com/view/facebook-sdk

   - many people recommended to use it. but
   - In rating page, people says that it's out of date and useless now. (because it's not updated and facebook rule's changed)
3. Facebook SDK by Xamarin from nuGet Package.

   - Xamarin developer says that there is no FB SDK for PCL project so far.

I'm curious that what is the good way to use facebook SDK?
It must have been being used by many developers who make app with using Xamarin.forms.

Are you guys uses Dependency Service with native SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No 3 is your best option. Correct, there is no Xamarin-Facebook binding library for PCL. However, it's fairly easy to make it happen with dependency injection. Either with the DependencyService or other container.

Comment: OK. Thanks so much!

Comment: @R4nc1d I'm trying but have a problem at beginning place. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39006615/xamarin-binding-ios-framework-runtime-error-could-not-create-an-native-instan

Comment: here I found this in other language but you can translate in chrome and translation is understandable. http://blog.ksharp.info/2017/02/integrate-facebook-audience-network-ads-in-your-xamarin-forms/

Comment: Yes, there are good examples available. One of them is my blogpost with github example: https://smellyc0de.wordpress.com/2018/03/09/using-native-facebook-login-button-in-xamarin-forms/